# Finding abundant numbers from 1 to 10 million using a sum

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

my task is to implement algorithm in C of finding abudant numbers from 1 to 10 million. Fistly I don't really understand mathematics.

There is several ways how to do it, but efficient and fast (for that BIG input 10 mil) might be by summing - NOT dividing, NOT multiplying, NOT EVEN using remainder after the division. Just sum.

But I'm really confused WHAT to sum. Please guys help, appreciate every single answer.

Comment: Ten million is not big if a computer does the work. Are there tight timing constraints, or is something that runs in under a second enough?

Comment: Only I know is that there are 2476736 abundant numbers under 10 million, common computer hardware is not able to check it even in hours, so I need more efficient algorithm and I know it's able to run under a second.

Comment: I think the "Therefore" you begin your second sentence with is not justified.

Comment: Do you want to *list* or *count* abundant numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following naive sieve approach takes only 30 seconds on my modest PC.

```
#define abLimit 10000000
int i, j, *xp;

xp = (int*) calloc(abLimit, 4);

for (i=2; i<abLimit, i++)
    for (j=i*2; j<abLimit; j+= i)
        xp[j] += i;

for (i=2; i<abLimit; i++)
    if (xp[i] > i)
        printf("%d is abundant\n", i);

free(xp);
```

Basically, it builds a table of $\sigma(n)$. It does not require any factorisation into primes, which makes it quick. I suggest you dry run it for a small value of abLimit to see what it's doing. Some pruning may reduce the run-time to under a second.

Comment: You're the boss. This actually works, it is now up to me to analyze what it is doing. Please help...
1) What is calloc? Is it supposed to be malloc, but it zero-initializes things in memory?
2) What is free()? Memory cleaning?
3) still figuring out what it's doing

Comment: I'm glad it works for you. Yes, calloc is memory allocation with zero initialisation and free unallocates the same memory.

Comment: Could you please explain what it's doing for the last time? Still don't understand :(

Comment: To find abundant numbers we need to find the sum of a number's proper factors, usually denoted by $\sigma$. All multiples of $6$, say, have $6$ as a proper factor, so $6$ must be included in the $\sigma$ sum of each multiple of $6$. The xp array in the code holds a table where we build up the $\sigma$ sums. When $i=6$, $j$ runs through $12, 18, 24, \dots$ and $6$ is added to the $\sigma$ sum for each $j$, i.e. for each multiple of $6$. $i$ takes the values of all possible factors and $j$ takes the values of all multiples of a given $i$, i.e. the numbers whose $\sigma$ sum must include $i$.

Answer (score 0):

A modern computer can factor the integers from 1 to 10 million in well under an hour, using even the most naive algorithms. Maybe post the code you've already written that is too slow, and we can help you spot problems with it?

However, if you're looking for something more efficient than computing $\sigma(n)$ directly, you could try a sieve approach: let's suppose you want to find all integers less than $N$ that are abundant.

First, you will need all of the primes less than $N$. You can compute these yourself, or use any of the several large tables available on the Internet. Let $p_i$ denote the $i$th prime. For each prime, compute the set $S_i$ of all nonnegative powers of that prime that are less than $N$.

Now, systematically examine all numbers formed by taking an element of $S_1$, multiplying it by an element of $S_2$, an element from $S_3$, etc. As you construct this product $n$, also construct $\sigma$ of that product, using the fact that $\sigma$ is multiplicative. If during the construction process the product ever exceeds $N$, skip it. Otherwise, compare $\sigma(n)$ to $2n$ and accumulate a list of the numbers you have constructed that are abundant.

If implemented poorly the above will be slower than brute-force search, so ask here or on Stackoverflow if you need any help.